# Error while loading Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Tags: oracle, powershell, powershell-2.0, odp.net

I am getting error while executing below command in powershell.

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Oracle\Oracle11gClientR1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll")
```

This is the error.

```
Exception calling "LoadFile" with "1" argument(s): " is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070
0C1)"
At line:1 char:32
+ [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile <<<< ("C:\Oracle\Oracle11gClientR1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll")
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Can anybody advise me what am i doing wrong?

I checked this path (

> C:\Oracle\Oracle11gClientR1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll

) and it is correct.

**Update:**
Powershell version is 2.

And i tried these as well

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "c:\Oracle\Oracle11gClientR1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"

Add-Type "c:\Oracle\Oracle11gClientR1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"
```

But no luck.

Comment: How you are running the command?

Comment: I am running in powershell as administrator

Comment: Than it shouldn't be the case. Try running again and if still error then show exactly how you are running? probably a screen capture.

Comment: I tried multiple times and this is one liner code. Nothing else is there. I have copy and pasted entire thing in the question.

Answer (score 2):

In that case, most probably you are running `PowerShell version 2.0` with `.NET Framework version 4.0` which is **incompatible**. Try using a compatible .NET Framework version. To check

Powershell version run the command

```
$PSVersionTable.psversion
```

To check .NET framework version installed run below command and check the 2nd line 3rd column data

```
gci "hklm:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP"
```

**EDIT:**

Few more suggestions:

Try using `LoadFrom()` instead like

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\Oracle\Oracle11gClientR1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll");
```

(OR) Try using `Add-Type` instead like

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "c:\Oracle\Oracle11gClientR1\ODP.NET\bin\2.x\Oracle.DataAccess.dll"
```

Also, make sure that you are not trying load 32-bit `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` from 64-bit Windows `Powershell`. I mean they both should be compaitible.

Comment: I ran the command and powershell version is 2 and dot net is 3 & 3.5